# Maven multimodule project use dependent project pom from repository

Tags: java, maven

I have multimodule Maven project and during mvn install I need to change pom in projectA (done with maven-resources-plugin, pom is created on special location (target/fixed-pom/pom.xml) and jar is installed into repo with mvn install-file --file target/projectA.jar --pom target/fixed-pom/pom.xml). I am able to install moduleA correctly into repository, but when projectB which has dependency on the projectA is built, installation fails because it is using unmodified pom from projectA. Can I somehow avoid this behaviour and say Maven to resolve also dependencies in the multi module project from repository?

```
parent
  |
  + --- projectA
  |
  + --- projectB
            |
            +----projectA
```

Comment: Dependencies are resolved at the start of the build, so there's no way you can have a dependency on the modified projectA that's about to be built, only on the unmodified one in the maven reactor. Changing build files during the build doesn't sound like a good approach anyway. What problem are you trying to solve with that?

Comment: what do you modify in the pom? you somehow fight against the system, that will cause issues. The only plugin I know that does a similar thing is the release plugin. It has its own lifecycle. I'm not convinced you need something like that - at least at the moment :)

Comment: I am modifying pom because I am building one project for multiple Scala compilers and don't want to use classifiers. Probably move to other dependency management tool will be solution.